# Mysql/php SELECT ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select like:

```
SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id = 5 ORDER BY id DESC
```

But I need to order my select with the "Name" column that is into another Table...
How can I do ?

Comment: post the table structure of the two tables

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT  xxx.*, yyy.name
FROM    xxx
JOIN    yyy
ON      yyy.x_id = xxx.id
WHERE   xxx.id = 5
ORDER BY
        yyy.name DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is heading in the right direction:

`SELECT * from xxx LEFT JOIN yyy ON yyy.name = xxx.whateverkey WHERE id = 5 ORDER BY yyy.name DESC`